# Using Spring's LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool with Quartz

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

Im trying to use the LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool with quartz but when i try to use it as the quartz taskexecutor I get this error.

ERROR:

arg.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 
[org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool] to required type [org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor] for property 'taskExecutor'.

Spring Config

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool">

</bean> 

<bean id="schedulerTarget" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" scope="singleton" lazy-init="false">
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey">
        <value>applicationContext</value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSrcBean"/>
    </property>
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref bean="txManager" />
    </property>
    <property name="taskExecutor">
        <ref bean="taskExecutor" />
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">QRTZ_</prop> 
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class">org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">Sched1</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">1</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export">false</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>  
</bean>
```

The whole purpose of this is to have Spring control any connection quartz makes. I already have a Spring transaction manager being used by the scheduler but its seems the scheduler will leave sleeping connections on my db.

Thnaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `LocalTaskExecutorThreadPool` yourself - `SchedulerFactoryBean` uses this internally to wrap a `TaskExecutor` in Quartz's `ThreadPool` interface.

`SchedulerFactoryBean` expects a `taskExecutor` object to be injected. You need to decide which implementation of `TaskExecutor` that you want to use.